# How to compare array entries to dictionary keys and return a dictionary value

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to make a python program that takes user input text or a file and changes each character into a value and then returns the result.
I have a user string that being read into a list.
I am trying to have a for loop go through that list and check each character against a dictionary key and then return the value in the dictionary. How would i go about doing that?
Thanks

Code so far:

```
for i in range (0, len(text)): 
    for j in alphabet.keys(): 
        if text[i].upper() == alphabet.values(): 
            j+=1
            print(alphabet.items()) 
    i+=1
```

Comment: at the very least post the code you've written so far.

Comment: It sounds like you've got most of the way there. Can you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: While textual explanations are welcomed, could you please provide some attempts you've tried? Example input/output? Desired outcomes?

Comment: For i in range (0,len(text)): for j in alphabet.keys(): if text[i].upper() == alphabet.values(): j+=1 print(alphabet.items())

Comment: I cant properly format it on my phone as im currently at work and dont have wifi for my laptop

Comment: No worries, I added it

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I actually discovered a different way of doing it that didn't require the use of dictionary when I was told about the ord() function

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in list_:
    try:
        print(d[item])
    except KeyError as e:
        print("{} not in d".format(e.args[0]))
```

Without seeing your code, I can't offer anything more relevant

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `string.maketrans` and `string.translate`

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans('abc', 'xyz')
>>> string.translate('the cat is bad', table)
'the zxt is yxd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code below is simply to create the dictionary that translates letters of an input into randomised corresponding values in a dict (i.e. each letter maps to another random letter). Points on your code:

1) `range()` automatically defaults to starting at `0` so `range(0, n)` is better just written as `range(n)`
2) You don't need to use `range()` at all here. `for letter in string` will take an input string and go through it, letter by letter. `for elephant in string` will do the same, each letter is being assigned to the name `elephant` in turn, so the fact that I chose to use `letter` instead is simply for readability. 
3) Using `keys()`, `values()` and `items()` is not the way to query a dictionary. You have two standard approaches; I could use `translation_dict[letter]` which will throw `KeyError` if the value of `letter` is not a key in the dictionary, or `translation_dict.get(letter)` which will return `None` if the key doesn't exist. In the below example, I used `get()` but also added another parameter ("not in dict") which replaces `None` as the default value if the letter isn't found as a key.

```
import string # For setup of example data
import random # For setup of example data

# Just creating the translation dictionary and fake user input
alphabet = list(string.uppercase)
translated = random.sample(alphabet, len(alphabet))
translation_dict = {i: j for i, j in zip(alphabet, translated)}

user_input = 'Hello'

# The loop you're trying

for letter in user_input:
    corresponding_value = translation_dict.get(letter.upper(), 'Not in dict')
    print(corresponding_value)
```